# Can you set up a condition in python to check for whole numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function in python which can calculate the most efficient ways to pack items.
a large pack will have the capacity to hold 25 items and small packet will have the capacity to hold 5 items.

def packages_needed (items, large_pack, small_pack)

I am really stuck on how to define / set up the reasoning

what I am thinking of is setting up a condition in which x/a is a whole number then z would just be that. and if the remainder is not 0 then z would whole number plus remainder.

im not sure if my reasoning makes sense, but I would really appreciate any suggestions/help.

what I have so far is:

````
z = 0
x = large_pack
y= small_pack

for a in items:```
````

Comment: To check if a number is an integer, you can use `isinstance(variable, int)`.

Comment: To split a number into integer and fractional part, you could use `x_int, x_frac = divmod(x,1)`

Comment: When there are < 25 items which results do you want? 1 large pack or several small packs? 7 for example. What about 13? That would require 3 small packs or 1 large pack.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow I'm trying to set up a function where it will utilize the large packs first and then small packs for remaining. for e.g. if I have 80 items then I want to use 3 large packs first and then 1 small pack

Comment: That sort of doesn't answer my question. I'm saying if you have 6 items you want 1 large pack then?

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow sorry I misunderstood your question, yes if its less than 25 then I'd need to use small_packs. The condition is to have each packet filled up completely if its being used

Comment: Does my answer solve your question? If not, comment on it.

Comment: thank you so much @mr_mooo_cow, your answer has is super helpful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard division floor operator(//) to determine how many times the number of items fits into the large and small size packs.

```
def division_ceiling(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """
    Accepts number of items. Returns how many small packs are needed.
    """
    return -1 * (-a // b)


def packages_needed(items: int) -> (int, int):
    """
    Accepts number of items. Returns tuple (large pack, small pack)
    """
    large_size = 25
    small_size = 5

    large_packs = items // large_size
    small_packs = division_ceiling(items - large_packs * large_size, small_size)
    return (large_packs, small_packs)
    """
    if you want 1-25 items to be 1 large pack then do this:
    if items <= 25:
        return (1, 0)
    else:
        large_packs = items // large_size
        small_packs = division_ceiling(items - large_packs * large_size, small_size)
        return (large_packs, small_packs)
    """


print(packages_needed(int(input("Number of items?"))))
```

---

```
Input: 31

Output: (1, 2)

Input: 6

Output: (0, 2)
```